# Old as1 array to edit

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have this old swf which play external swf in array with random order, but how do I edit it to make the array go in order(01>02>03...) and after, restart in loop?

```
filename1 = new Array("01.swf","02.swf","03.swf","04.swf","05.swf","06.swf");
a = filename1.length;
b = random(a);
_root.movieTarget.loadMovie(filename1[b]);
movieTarget._xscale = 80;
movieTarget._yscale = 80;
```

#**Update** 
(this is an old screensaver that I use on an equally old pc, which I want to modify for fun) ... many years ago I knew a little bit of java but now I just don't understand anything about this actionscript, so I ask you for help...
So like this...

```
filename1 = new Array("01.swf","02.swf","03.swf","04.swf","05.swf","06.swf"); //(many others swf)
filename1.push(filename1.shift(//total number of swf))
_root.movieTarget.loadMovie(filename1[//total number of swf]);
movieTarget._xscale = 80;
movieTarget._yscale = 80;
```

it doesn't work (with same code at last frame of any external swf (?)).

Comment: Where on earth did you find **AS1**? And why even care to use it? That's from like 1995 or such!! Anyways... **(1)** Remove the `random(a)` code line. **(2)** Check the docs for how to detect when  a movieclip has finished playing and add such an `eventListener` together with a _handler_ function to process things when such event happens. **(3)** The  handler function updates some `playNum` variable by incrementing it **+1** using `playNum++` then do your `loadMovie(filename1[ playNum ]);` and also give that loaded Movie the same "ending" event listener & handler... This way it will loop.

Comment: @VC.One **A.push(A.shift());** to rotate the items rather than just remove randomizing indices.

Comment: @Organis I hear you but not sure how the Asker can use that to get an incremental result for usage with the `.loadMovie` code. Also how can they loop back to `01.swf`after the **shift** happens on `06.swf`? Constantly trimming the array would stop their ability to go back to earlier state, right? Simpler to just set a **global** number that reps their position in the array and adjust that number as/when needed (_eg:_ when loaded movie ends playing).

Comment: @VC.One If you will continuously perform that shift+push and load the [0]-th element of the **Array**, you will get to the initial state, eventually.

Comment: Seems like useful advise. So `loadMovie(filename1[0]);` as long as there's a previous line doing `filename1.push(filename1.shift());`? I hope the Asker is paying attention to these tips and gives feedback (hopefully not just waiting for free code).

Comment: @VC.One this is an old screensaver that I use on an equally old pc, which I want to modify for fun ... many years ago I knew a little bit of java but now I just don't understand anything about this actionscript, so I ask for help, see update.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The thing stopping me answering you is not knowing how to check, using **AS1**, when a loaded SWF has reached its last frame (in order to trigger another function that plays the next file in order). Normally in AS3 we use **enterFrame** to check playhead position example: `if ( MClip.currentFrame == MClip.totalFrames )` means the SWF has reached ending or last frame.